# How to find start & end index of a sub-string from a string

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am trying to get the start & end position for my sub-string

```
mystr = "I live at 2 Inchydoney Island. Inchydoney, Co Cork"
search_str = '2 Inchydoney Island. Inchydoney, Co Cork'

result = [i+1 for i,w in enumerate(mystr.split()) if w.lower() == search_str]
print(result)
```

I tried with piece of code, but it doesn't return anything.

Expected Output

```
[11,48]
```

Comment: a simple way to do this is to check where the substring is using str.find: `mystr.find(search_str)` this will either return where the substring starts or -1 if ifs not there. if the string is found you just need to add the length of the search_str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) or [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to find the position of a substring in a longer string.

```
mystr = "I live at 2 Inchydoney Island. Inchydoney, Co Cork"
search_str = '2 Inchydoney Island. Inchydoney, Co Cork'
start = mystr.index(search_str)
end = start + len(search_str)
```